# Scanner nextInt() vs nextLine() reading from console .... why can I use nextInt() without nextLine()?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Why don't I have to use nextLine when entering numbers into console on separate lines?  I expected console to interpret end of each line having \n but program works the same whether I use nextLine() after each nextInt().  Using Eclipse.

```
// Example used
10 5      // # lines to read ,  divisor
22        //  if # divisible by divisor, count++ 
15 
10 
25 
17 
13 
15 
10 
7 
9
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = getNumber(keyboard);
    int k = getNumber(keyboard);
    int numLinesPassed = getNumberPassCriteria(keyboard, n, k);
    System.out.println("# Passed: " + numLinesPassed);
}
    
public static int getNumber(Scanner keyboard) {
    return keyboard.nextInt();
}
    
public static int getNumberPassCriteria(Scanner keyboard, int n, int k) {
    int counter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int value = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (value % k == 0) {
            counter++;
        }
        //keyboard.nextLine();    not understand why I don't need this 
    }

    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably confused with [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/15244370).

This is only a problem if you are reading, or trying to read the next line after the number using `nextLine`.

Why? `nextInt` reads a token, defined as text between delimiter**s** (default white space including linefeed and carriage return), that means, if the input starts with one or more delimiter, these are ignored (discarded). `nextLine` does not read tokens, it just reads up to the newline; so if the next character is a newline, an empty string is returned.

Easy to test: just enter a couple of empty lines between the numbers - your code should read them without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Because the default delimiter for `Scanner` is this pattern

```
\p{javaWhitespace}+
```

<s>(Note: this exact pattern is not explicitly documented, but it's what you obtain calling the `delimiter()` method of `Scanner` when you instantiate one without explicitly specifying a different separator)</s>

EDIT

As per [user15244370](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15244370/user15244370)'s suggestion this mess of references I made is actually documented directly in the `Scanner` documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#default-delimiter). You can skip directly to the list below.

---

The meaning of that pattern is documented in the documentation for the [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) class which itself refers to the [`Character.isWhitespace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(char)) method
That pattern means a sequence of at least one of

- a Unicode space character (SPACE_SEPARATOR, LINE_SEPARATOR, or PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR) but is not also a non-breaking space ('\u00A0', '\u2007', '\u202F').
  *'\t', U+0009 HORIZONTAL TABULATION.
- '\n', U+000A LINE FEED.
- '\u000B', U+000B VERTICAL TABULATION.
- '\f', U+000C FORM FEED.
- '\r', U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN.
- '\u001C', U+001C FILE SEPARATOR.
- '\u001D', U+001D GROUP SEPARATOR.
- '\u001E', U+001E RECORD SEPARATOR.
- '\u001F', U+001F UNIT SEPARATOR.

Which includes newline (the second bullet point).

Comment: documentation of delimiter has its own html anchor: [default-pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#default-delimiter) And documentation of [`reset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#reset()) shows pattern (and a bit more) ((OK, it's a bit hidden))

Comment: I had the *pleasure* to search it some time ago... almost lost my faith in Javas documentation